# Option Intel (R) PRO/1000 PCI-Express Gigabit Ethernet support cannot be set to y？

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel-modules

I tailored my system using the Linux 6.4.0 kernel and used the Intel I210 network card, but `ifconfig -a` was unable to recognize it. I searched online and said that I can set option `Intel(R) PRO/1000 PCI-Express Gigabit Ethernet support` as needed, but I cannot set it to `Y`, it can only be `m` or `n`.

```
Location:
  -> Device Drivers
    -> Network device support (NETDEVICES [=y]) 
      -> Ethernet driver support (ETHERNET [=y]) 
        -> Intel devices (NET_VENDOR_INTEL [=y]) 
         -> Intel(R) PRO/1000 PCI-Express Gigabit Ethernet support (E1000E [=m])
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question then?  If the code is not designed to be anything but a module, then it's not: you can't force it without editing kernel sources.